# getting randomly generated passwd for Ubuntu 16.04 cloudimage

Tags: 16.04, cloud, passwd

I am having a hard time getting the supposedly randomly generated passwd for the amd64 qcow2 image here:

https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/releases/16.04/release/

I found the (perhaps outdated?) instructions here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEC/Images

Things seem to have changed, and I don't see the line in the console output, and ctrl-alt-3 for serial console doesn't work for me (i entered via virsh console vm_name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use libguestfs-tool to clear the root passwd.

```
    sudo apt install libguestfs-tools
    virt-edit -a disk.img /etc/passwd -e 's/^root:.*?:/root::/'
```

See http://libguestfs.org/guestfs-recipes.1.html under "Remove root password (Linux)"

But why can't Ubuntu just put up a decent page on how to use their CloudImages for novices???